Interaction Plotting
How to draw an interaction diagram like the ones in the research articles. I am trying to plot an interaction diagram of a continuous predictor variable and a binary interaction variable on a continuous response variable. For e.g., $Y=β+β1X1+β2X2+β3X1*X2$, where $X1$ is continuous, and $X2$ is binary, and $Y$ is continuous. I find after regression analysis that there is a positive interaction effect on the response variable. I want to graphically support the findings. I see many research papers do that. But in the graph on the x-axis, I see that the continuous predictor variable of the equation is divided into low and high. How is this classification made when the variable is continuous?
So I found out how to plot in R using interaction.plot() function. But my diagram looks like this. Can anyone explain why?

Code I use:
interaction.plot(x.factor = Data_cleaningsave$IExM,
                 trace.factor = Data_cleaningsave$Stlog,  
                 response = Data_cleaningsave$logres1,fun = median,xlab="IM", 
                 ylab="RM", trace.label="ST")



@Shawn After your comment I changed the code. The graph looks like the above

"I find after regression analysis that there is a positive interaction effect on the response variable" Because X2 is categorical, there isn't just one interaction term - there are many (usually one for every group in X2, minus the reference category). If you look at your model output, this will become clear.

Standard interaction plots are for discrete factors. Chances are that R here interpreted every value of a continuous variable as a separate factor level (you may check whether the listed values are indeed all values taken in your data).

Continuous values of the data set:                                                                                                 Stlog
0.698970004
0
0.301029996
1
0.903089987
0.301029996
0.602059991
0.477121255
0.602059991
0.602059991
0.77815125
0.602059991
1.146128036
0
0.301029996
0.301029996
0.77815125
0.84509804
0.301029996
0.602059991
0.698970004

0.84509804
0.84509804
0.301029996
0
0.698970004
1.079181246
0
0.602059991
0.602059991
0.77815125
0.903089987
0.301029996
0.301029996
0.301029996
0.903089987
0.602059991
0.77815125
0.84509804
0.77815125
0
0.301029996
0

I provide an example of how you hand plot interactions here. In essence, the interaction terms represent adjusted intercepts and slopes contingent on what you put into the model. With more terms, more adjustments are made, depending on how they are modeled.
Importantly, the second argument of the interaction.plot() function specifies how the interaction lines are traced (example here), but it appears by the naming of the variable that you have fed this argument a continuous variable.
